# Makefile Circular Dependency + No such file error

Tags: gcc, makefile, avr-gcc, atmega

I have been trying to write a makefile for my avr gcc project using a template. This is my first time writing one (so far i've just been using the default inbuilt makefile in AVR Studio 4)

When i try to compile I get there errors

```
make: Circular Makefile.out <- Makefile dependency dropped.
make: Circular all.out <- all dependency dropped.
avr-gcc  -I.  -g -mmcu=atmega8  -Os  -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char -Wall -std=gnu99 -DF_CPU=8000000 -Wa,-ahlms=../8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY.lst -c ../8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY.c -o ../8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY.o
avr-gcc  -Wl,-Map,8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY .out .map -mmcu=atmega8  -lm  -o 8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY .out  ../8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY.o 
avr-gcc: .out: No such file or directory
avr-gcc: .map: No such file or directory
avr-gcc: .out: No such file or directory
```

This is my makefile

```
#########  AVR Project Makefile Template   ######### 
######                                        ###### 
######    Copyright (C) 2003-2005,Pat Deegan, ###### 
######            Psychogenic Inc             ###### 
######          All Rights Reserved           ###### 
######                                        ###### 
###### You are free to use this code as part  ###### 
###### of your own applications provided      ###### 
###### you keep this copyright notice intact  ###### 
###### and acknowledge its authorship with    ###### 
###### the words:                             ###### 
######                                        ###### 
###### "Contains software by Pat Deegan of    ###### 
###### Psychogenic Inc (www.psychogenic.com)" ###### 
######                                        ###### 
###### If you use it as part of a web site    ###### 
###### please include a link to our site,     ###### 
###### http://electrons.psychogenic.com  or   ###### 
###### http://www.psychogenic.com             ###### 
######                                        ###### 
#################################################### 


##### This Makefile will make compiling Atmel AVR 
##### micro controller projects simple with Linux 
##### or other Unix workstations and the AVR-GCC 
##### tools. 
##### 
##### It supports C, C++ and Assembly source files. 
##### 
##### Customize the values as indicated below and : 
##### make 
##### make disasm 
##### make stats 
##### make hex 
##### make writeflash 
##### make gdbinit 
##### or make clean 
##### 
##### See the http://electrons.psychogenic.com/ 
##### website for detailed instructions 


#################################################### 
#####                                          ##### 
#####              Configuration               ##### 
#####                                          ##### 
##### Customize the values in this section for ##### 
##### your project. MCU, PROJECTNAME and       ##### 
##### PRJSRC must be setup for all projects,   ##### 
##### the remaining variables are only         ##### 
##### relevant to those needing additional     ##### 
##### include dirs or libraries and those      ##### 
##### who wish to use the avrdude programmer   ##### 
#####                                          ##### 
##### See http://electrons.psychogenic.com/    ##### 
##### for further details.                     ##### 
#####                                          ##### 
#################################################### 


#####         Target Specific Details          ##### 
#####     Customize these for your project     ##### 

# Name of target controller 
# (e.g. 'at90s8515', see the available avr-gcc mmcu 
# options for possible values) 
MCU=atmega8 

# id to use with programmer 
# default: PROGRAMMER_MCU=$(MCU) 
# In case the programer used, e.g avrdude, doesn't 
# accept the same MCU name as avr-gcc (for example 
# for ATmega8s, avr-gcc expects 'atmega8' and 
# avrdude requires 'm8') 
PROGRAMMER_MCU=m8 

# Name of our project 
# (use a single word, e.g. 'myproject') 
PROJECTNAME=8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY 

# Source files 
# List C/C++/Assembly source files: 
# (list all files to compile, e.g. 'a.c b.cpp as.S'): 
# Use .cc, .cpp or .C suffix for C++ files, use .S 
# (NOT .s !!!) for assembly source code files. 
PRJSRC=../8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY.c 

# additional includes (e.g. -I/path/to/mydir) 
INC= 

# libraries to link in (e.g. -lmylib) 
LIBS= 

# Optimization level, 
# use s (size opt), 1, 2, 3 or 0 (off) 
OPTLEVEL=s 


#################################################### 
#####                Config Done               ##### 
#####                                          ##### 
##### You shouldn't need to edit anything      ##### 
##### below to use the makefile but may wish   ##### 
##### to override a few of the flags           ##### 
##### nonetheless                              ##### 
#####                                          ##### 
#################################################### 


##### Flags #### 

# HEXFORMAT -- format for .hex file output 
HEXFORMAT=ihex 

# compiler
CFLAGS=-I. $(INC) -g -mmcu=$(MCU) -O$(OPTLEVEL) \
    -fpack-struct -fshort-enums             \
    -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char    \
    -Wall -std=gnu99 -DF_CPU=8000000               \
    -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword                  \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.c=.lst)))


# assembler 
ASMFLAGS =-I. $(INC) -mmcu=$(MCU)        \
    -x assembler-with-cpp            \
    -Wa,-gstabs,-ahlms=$(firstword   \
        $(<:.S=.lst) $(<.s=.lst))


# linker 
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Map,$(TRG).map -mmcu=$(MCU) \
    -lm $(LIBS)

##### executables #### 
CC=avr-gcc 
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy 
REMOVE=rm -f 

##### automatic target names #### 
TRG=$(PROJECTNAME).out 
HEXROMTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).hex 
HEXTRG=$(HEXROMTRG) $(PROJECTNAME).ee.hex 

# Define all object files. 

# Start by splitting source files by type
#  C
CFILES=$(filter %.c, $(PRJSRC))
#  Assembly
ASMFILES=$(filter %.S, $(PRJSRC))


# List all object files we need to create
OBJDEPS=$(CFILES:.c=.o)    \
    $(ASMFILES:.S=.o)



.SUFFIXES : C .o .out .s .S \
    .hex .ee.hex .h .hh .hpp

.PHONY: writeflash clean stats gdbinit stats 

# Make targets: 
# all, disasm, stats, hex, writeflash/install, clean 
all: $(TRG) 

#disasm: $(DUMPTRG) stats 

#stats: $(TRG)
#   $(OBJDUMP) -h $(TRG)
#   $(SIZE) $(TRG) 

hex: $(HEXTRG) 


#writeflash: hex 
#install: writeflash 

#$(DUMPTRG): $(TRG) 
#   $(OBJDUMP) -S  $< > $@


$(TRG): $(OBJDEPS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TRG) $(OBJDEPS)



#### Generating assembly ####
# asm from C
%.s: %.c
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# asm from (hand coded) asm
%.s: %.S
    $(CC) -S $(ASMFLAGS) $< > $@

# asm from C++ 
#.cpp.s .cc.s .C.s : 
#   $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 



#### Generating object files #### 
# object from C
.c.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


# object from C++ (.cc, .cpp, .C files) 
#.cc.o .cpp.o .C.o : 
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

# object from asm 
.S.o :
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


#### Generating hex files #### 
# hex files from elf 
#####  Generating a gdb initialisation file    ##### 
.out.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text                    \
        -j .data                       \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@

.out.ee.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom                  \
        --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@

#### Cleanup #### 
clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(TRG) $(TRG).map $(DUMPTRG)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDEPS)
    $(REMOVE) $(LST) $(GDBINITFILE)
    $(REMOVE) $(GENASMFILES)
    $(REMOVE) $(HEXTRG)



#####                    EOF                   #####
```

Any help what I have done wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: My mistake but I should have posted this on electronics.stackexchange.com. Can the moderator please move this question to there

Comment: Makefiles are programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing space in the definition of `PROJECTNAME`, so the `TRG` variable gets set to `8_8_LED_DOT_MATRIX_DISPLAY .out` and your link command ends up referring to the file `.out` (and the file `.map` too, because there seems to be a trailing space in the definition of `TRG` as well). That's the culprit for both the "no such file" errors and the circular dependencies.

The reason for the circular dependency errors is a bit subtle: Because of the trailing space, the rule

```
$(TRG) : $(OBJDEPS)
    <command>
```

results in

```
% : %.out
    <command>
```

Since your `all` target is not marked as `.PHONY`, `make` considers this rule when checking if `all` has to be rebuilt. On the other hand, `.out` is a built-in suffix and `make` has a built-in rule

```
%.out : %
    @rm -f $@
    cp $< $@
```

Combined with the above, this results in a circular dependency for `all`. The same applies to `Makefile`, because `make` always tries to rebuild every file it processes.

tl;dr: Remove the trailing space in `PROJECTNAME` and `TRG`.